# How to run two commands together?

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a shell script (myScript.sh) comprising of a set of commands of the following form:

```
command1 #first run
command1 #second run
command1 #third run
```

Now I want to find the maximum RAM consumed by each individual run of command1. I can find the maximum RAM consumed by command 1 by running in a 
separate terminal the command:

```
smem -c "command pss" | grep "command1"
```

In order to find the maximum RAM consumed by first, second and third run individually I have the run command1 and smem on different terminals manually in an interleaved fashion

```
command1 #terminal 1
smem -c "command pss" | grep "command1" #terminal 2 in a loop to get maximum memory
command1 #terminal 1
smem -c "command pss" | grep "command1" #terminal 2 in a loop to get maximum memory
command1 #terminal 1
smem -c "command pss" | grep "command1" #terminal 2 in a loop to get maximum memory/
```

Is there any way by which I may automate this process within a single shell script or program using either linux commands or python?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Linux, but you can do this on a Mac under OS X:

```
/usr/bin/time -l <command> 2>&1 | grep -i max
```

Sample output:

```
/usr/bin/time -l sleep 1 2>&1 | grep -i max
557056  maximum resident set size                 # <--- program used 557kB
```

or, full output:

```
/usr/bin/time -l sleep 1
        1.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
    557056  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       145  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
         2  involuntary context switches
```